# JavaScript regex is giving false positives

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm checking the first character of a string for any non-alphanumeric characters from a multi-line textbox. If I pass in this string in, I get some hits.

```
ATest
BTest2
CAnother1
DThen some
2 More to go
FAny other some-day
```

Here's the javascript code:

```
function CheckFirstAlphaNum(textToTest, valueLabel, pattern, warningMessage)     
{
    var textValues = textToTest.split("\n");
    pattern = pattern || /([A-Za-z0-9]+)/gm;
    warningMessage = warningMessage || "The first character of a value in '" + valueLabel + "' has an invalid character. Please consider revising it."

    var goodText = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < textValues.length; ++i) {
        //alert(textValues[i]);
        var firstChar = textValues[i].substring(0, 1);
        if (!pattern.test(firstChar)) {
            alert(firstChar);
            alert(pattern);
            goodText = false;
        }
    }
    if (goodText != true) { alert(warningMessage); }
    return goodText;
}
```

Any ideas why? It fails on B, D, and F, so it seems like every other line.

Comment: It could be related line endings. Some systems use `\r\n` for the line ending, and if you are only splitting on `\n` you might have some troublesome whitespace in your strings. Try this  `var firstChar = textValues[i].trim().substring(0, 1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because your regex is incorrect.

I'm not sure what the `/gm` switches at the end do, but try:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9]/
```

---

From your original regex, a couple of points to note:

1. `^` matches the start of the string
2. `+` is not useful if you only care about a single character

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're using the `g` (global) modifier in your regex.

Run this code in your JS console to check that  `test()` returns alternating `true` and `false`

```
r = /([A-Za-z0-9]+)/g
r.test('a')
> true
r.test('a')
> false
r.test('a')
> true
...
```

Removing the `g` modifier results in the regex always returning true for a string that matches. Since you're testing just one character using the multiline modifier `m` and the `+` (one or more matches) are unnecessary also.

Answer (score 0):

Your text most probably has Windows line breaks `\r\n` rather than only `\n`. So splitting at `\n` will result in `\r` entries on every other array index.

Those `\r` will "fire" the regex .test() method because it's not alphanumeric.

Try this

```
var textValues = textToTest.split("\r\n");
```